# Average Aragonite:Calcite ratio in biogenic CaCO3 in the oceans

Tags: ocean, oceanography, geobiology, carbonate

I wonder what the average ratio between aragonite and calcite is during the precipitation of biogenic calcium carbonate in seawater. I know some species are aragonite-favouring and some perfer using calcite. I also know that aragonite is about 50% more soluble than calcite, and therefore less common.

If any of you would know a (coarse) average between these two (with references if possible)?

Answer (score 5):

After some more research, the conclusion is that aragonite is somewhere between 10 and 50% of total CaCO<sub>3</sub> production:

Aragonite, calcite-Mg and calcite are the 3 main species of marine CaCO<sub>3</sub>. Aragonite is unlikely to be a major component of the total CaCO<sub>3</sub> flux (Berelson, 2007), though the exact contribution is uncertain and falls in the range of 10-50% of global CaCO<sub>3</sub> production (Gangstø, 2008). Minimum values of 12% (Berner and Honjo, 1981) and 13% (Fabry and Deuser, 1992) have been reported based on sediment traps. Calcite-Mg contributes ~8% (Fabry and Deuser, 1992) to 24% (Morse, 2006) to CaCO<sub>3</sub> production. The sediment trap-based contribution of aragonite of ~12% is thought to be lower than the actual contribution of aragonite to CaCO<sub>3</sub> production because aragonite is about 1.5 times more soluble than calcite and therefore more depleted than calcite in the sediment trap records.

An educated guess of me would therefore be ~20% aragonite, ~10% calcite-Mg and ~70% calcite globally on average.